# How can I use Apps like Cortana with UAC disabled and no password requirement on boot?

Tags: uac, windows-10, cortana

I don't want the annoyances of UAC constantly asking "Are you sure?" nor the annoyance of having extra steps to preform (login) when my laptop boots up. There isn't actually any good reason to have to have all of those annoyances to be able to use apps like Cortana but they were designed in there anyway.

Do you know how to keep a zero-step login and UAC disabled/off while also maintaining app functionality?

Comment: If you don't want UAC, don't use Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, and even a C# app that uses DLL hooks to automatically grab the UAC confirmation window and click the or press the "Yes" button, the solution is to disable UAC completely, and the MS account (for faster login).

Why? Because:

- Cortana isn't any more useful than "ask Google"
- it's weird to talk at your computer unless you're showing it to someone
- and because being able to use Cortana isn't nearly worth the constant "Are you sure you want to run this?" UAC popups

TL;DR: I'll gladly take the cumulative productivity boost in exchange for the low risk of falling for malware traps.

Comment: I'm a power user and spend most of the day on Windows 10, yet I would hardly consider UAC popups frequent enough to be annoying. Certainly less of a nuisance than Apple, which requires you to put in your password twice to update a free app or four times to rent a movie... Also, Cortana is more useful than "Ask Google" because it can open and perform actions in apps.

Answer (score 1):

The Store apps and all apps that use the WinRT libraries require enabled UAC. The UAC provides the sandbox to isolate the Apps and prevent bad apps from harm your device.

If you don't want UAC, you can't use the Store Apps. This is the same like in Windows 8/8.1

Comment: I don't mind not being able to use the store apps with the exception of Cortana. Is there any way to use cortana with UAC off and no login at all?

Comment: no, this is not possible, because Cortana is a StartApp.